# Slow Search Queries - How to exclude pages, media, excerpt, authors, private posts?

Tags: query, search

So I have this from *Query Monitor*:

```
AND (((zp_posts.post_title LIKE '%mercedes%')
OR (zp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%mercedes%')
OR (zp_posts.post_content LIKE '%mercedes%'))) 
AND zp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')
AND (zp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR zp_posts.post_author = 1
AND zp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY zp_posts.post_title LIKE '%mercedes%' DESC, zp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I would like the searches queries to target only post_title and post_content, exclude all others parts. Any idea in achieving that?

Comment: what is that? there is no wordpress core API that will generate such a query.

Comment: what is what? I was asking how to exclude everything else, except posts, from search results.

Comment: your query can not be fast. if this is a query you written on your own, whatever you are trying to do is wrong. If this is a plugin you use... well without the actual code it will be impossible to help you change it

Comment: Query Monitor gives me a very similar query on a search page `/?s`.  I don't have any plugins or custom functions that would affect search. The caller is `WP_Query->get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Include_Custom_Post_Types_in_Search_Results) to change the query. I'd suggest creating a custom plugin, so that if you ever change your theme your modifications will still apply.

To get you started, here's how you can set the post types being searched:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'post' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

You would continue to add `$query->set` statements inside the conditionals to further customize what fields to search.

One other option would be to write a completely custom query and call that from your search rather than using WP's built-in query. You might want to benchmark that solution to see whether it is any faster than the `pre_get_posts` way.

Comment: if ( !is_admin() ?

Comment: Queries run in wp-admin too. This prevents it from causing issues in admin, restricting it to the main query only on the front end.

Comment: @WebElaine or @Ciprian, can you post the code that limits the search to only specified fields like `post_content`? Thanks!